# How to Append a string to the end of a RegEx Capture Group

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have a hostname recorded in my ElasticSearch logs in the following form:

```
ip-10-109-28-254.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

I've written a RegEx to capture only to IP address (including the "ip" prefix).

This is the RegEx:

```
/(ip-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})/
```

The ElasticSearch Query used is:

```
"find":"terms","field":"host.hostname","query":"fields.Application:$Collection.$Application"}
```

Which returns: **ip-10-109-28-254**

This is exactly what I want, however I would like to append a wildcard character to the end of this string so it now reads:

```
ip-10-109-28-254*
```

How do I modify my RegEx to include the * suffix? Is this possible?

**Use Case**

I'm using RegEx in a Query Variable in Kibana. You are allowed ONE RegEx expression so appended the suffix needs to be done in one expression.  I'll use the value to make ElasticSearch wildcard queries (e.g. host.hotname:$QueryVariableName). This will allow me to do a wildcard search for the hostname.

I've tried a variety of combinations and I can get it to work.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: `/(ip-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}\*)/`

Comment: Can you point me towards the documentation for the `$QueryVariableName` syntax? As far as I was aware, this does not work in Kibana.

Comment: If it is powered with ElasticSearch regex, you need something like `"ip-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}\\*"`, and it will require full string match.

Comment: @IanGabes Here is the info on using query variable in Grafana: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/elasticsearch/#query-variable

Comment: I tried both suggestions: "/(ip-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}\*)/" and ""ip-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}\\*" without success.  I think the problem is is that RegEx will be looking for "\\*" as part of the source data so there will be no match.

Comment: Can you share the kibana query you're currently using?

Comment: Sure Joe.  I updated the original post with a screen shot.  Hopefully that will provide more context.  Thanks for looking!